# Android scrollTo() doesn't show new items for ListView

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I'm trying to implement some logic for a custom `ListView`. In its `OnTouchListener`'s `onTouch()` method I check if some conditions were met, and if so, scroll the `ListView` up/down, depending on what direction user's finger is moving in. Now, when I scroll `ListView` down to show new items from the bottom, those items don't appear. I tried to call `ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` every time I call `scrollTo()`, but it doesn't work. I also googled this problem, but I couldn't found a solid solution/explanation.

Here's some code sample:

```
@Override public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //Some code

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        deltaY = event.getRawY() - downY;
                        if(//Some condition) {
                        listView.scrollTo(0, (int) -deltaY);
                        isScrolling = true;
                }
                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try doing scrollTo to wait a second after notifyDataSetChanged.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       listView.scrollTo(0, (int) -deltaY);
    }
}, 300)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **scrollListBy** instead of **scrollTo**. But there is a limitation of using this, you can only use it on or above **KitKat** version. Use it like this :-

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            listView.scrollListBy((int) -deltaY);
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't really rely on that since I need it to work with lower versions too

Comment: Hey, i've searched for resolving this problem below **KitKat**, but i got nothing :(

Comment: Thank you for trying, I appreciate that :) @Rahul Sonpaliya